# How to call a non static member function from a static member function without passing class instance

Tags: c++, class, static, struct

I need to call a non static member function from a static member function of the same class.
The static function is a callback. It can receive only void as data, though which i pass a char*. So i cannot directly provide the class instance to the callback. I can pass a structure instead of char to the callback function. Can anyone give eg code to use the non static member function in a static member function . and use the structure in the static member function to use the instance of the class to call the non static member function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally such a callback would look like this:

```
void Callback( void* data)
{
    CMyClass *myClassInstance = static_cast<CMyClass *>(data);
    myClassInstance->MyInstanceMethod();
}
```

Of course, you need to make sure, data points to an instance of your class. E.g.

```
CMyClass* data = new CMyClass();
FunctionCallingMyCallback( data, &Callback);
delete data;
```

Now, if I understand you correctly, you need to also pass a char*.
You can either wrap both in a struct and unwrap it in the callback like so:

```
MyStruct* data = new MyStruct();
data->PtrToMyClass = new CMyClass();
data->MyCharPtr = "test";
FunctionCallingMyCallback( data, &Callback);
delete data->PtrToMyClass;
delete data;


void Callback( void* data)
{
    MyStruct *myStructInstance = static_cast<MyStruct *>(data);
    CMyClass *myClassInstance = myStructInstance->PtrToMyClass;
    char * myData = myStructInstance->MyCharPtr;
    myClassInstance->MyInstanceMethod(myData);
}
```

or, if you can modify the definition of CMyClass, put all the necessary data in class members, so that you can use a callback as in the first example.

Comment: Good answer - +1 - but you shouldn't use c-style casts IMHO.

Comment: thanks Henrick it worked. I tried the same thing before, except that i dint create a pointer for the struct.

Answer (score 2):

If your instance is a singleton (usually implemented using a private or protected constructor and a static pointer to itself) you can do e.g.:

```
class MyClass {
private:
  MyClass():myInstance(0) {}

  static MyClass *myInstance;

  void callback();
public:
  ~MyClass() {}

  static MyClass *getInstance();

  static void myCallback();    
};

MyClass *MyClass::getInstance() {
  if(!myInstance) {
    myInstance = new MyClass;
  }
  return myInsance;
}    

void MyClass::callback() {
 // non-static callback
}

void MyClass::myCallback() {
  getInstance()->callback();
}
```

If you don't use a singleton but you can pass the instance cast to a `void *` then you can do this instead:

```
void MyClass::myCallback(void *data) {
  MyClass *instance = static_cast<MyClass *>(data);
  instance->callback();
}
```

Comment: It seams that the getInstance is usefull in order to enter in the name space of the class. Is that right? Is that the only purpose?

Comment: @Jonathan The `getInstance` method in combination with the private/protected constructor allows you to limit access to the single instance.

Comment: You could add to your first example different static callbacks "myCallback<1-4>" calling the same method MyClass::callback with a const parameter. Defining "myCallback<1-4>" with a XMacro would be nice.

Comment: Don't you get an "Invalid use of member 'myInstance' in static member function'  getInstance() error?

Comment: @Mich I think `myInstance` should also be set to static here

Comment: Yep I think so too. @Kargath - edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

struct A;
A *oneObj = NULL;


struct A
{
  A(){
    oneObj=this;
  }
  ~A(){
    oneObj=NULL;
  }
  void foo()
  {
  }

  static void boo()
  {
    assert( NULL != oneObj );
    oneObj->foo();
  }
};

int main()
{
  A onlyOne;
  A::boo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to call a non `static` member function from a static member
>   function of the same `class`. The `static` function is a callback. It can
>   receive only void as data, though which i pass a `char*`.

This shows that present design is **flawed or inproper**. IMHO, you should rather think of changing the design. Just imagine if you somehow get the things working but what about the maintainability an readability of the code.

I would suggest that you should change your callback function to different signature and made according changes.

```
class A {
//...
  static void CallBack (A *pObj)
  {
    // logic
  }
};
```