# How can i call an other function from static Thread entry point function in c++?

Tags: c++, qt, pthreads

I have in my code a thread and an entry point function like this:

```
    static void *readerThreadEntryPoint(void *arg)

    void *MainWindow::readerThreadEntryPoint(void *arg) {
    MODES_NOTUSED(arg);     
}
```

and i want to call a function with this code

```
    QBytearray data = socket->ReadAll();
```

how can i do ?
i have an error: invalid use of member ‘MainWindow::socket’ in static member function QTcpSocket *socket; 
I have 2 Threads, one to read the buffer and an other to process the data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a pointer to an instance of the class as the `arg` during thread creation.  That way, rather than marking `arg` as "not used" you can do this inside your static method:

```
void *MainWindow::readerThreadEntryPoint(void *arg) {
    MainWindow* self = static_cast<MainWindow*>(arg);
```

From then on you can use `self` similar to the implicit `this` you would have had with non-static methods.  Or you can simply call another method which is not static but does the real work, like this:

```
self->readerThreadEntryPointImpl(); // non-static method call
```

Comment: i found yesterday this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894977/how-to-call-a-non-static-member-function-from-a-static-member-function-without-p and i tried this code MainWindow *instance = static_cast<MainWindow *>(arg);
    QByteArray data= instance->socket->readAll(); but i have a SIGSEGV error from the debugger, is it the same with your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found, 
i changed this line

```
pthread_create(&Modes.reader_thread, NULL, readerThreadEntryPoint, NULL);
```

to this one

```
pthread_create(&Modes.reader_thread, NULL, readerThreadEntryPoint, this);
```

and then i used the suggestion of @John Zwinck and i wrote the following code,

`MainWindow *instance = static_cast<MainWindow *>(arg);
    QByteArray data= instance->socket->readAll();`

and i solved the SIGSEGV error!

Comment: Right, this is exactly what I suggested.