# Accessing this pointer in static function in cpp

Tags: c++, static, this

I have a cpp class and few methods defined in it.
One of the static methods needs to call the non static method of the same class. I cant do this using "this" pointer as in static function "this" pointer cant be used.

I need someway to access the pointer to the same class in the static method in cpp...can someone pls help

Comment: _"I need someway to access the pointer to the same class in the static method"_ You can define a `MyClass*` pointer parameter for the `static` class member function and pass it there.

Comment: you mean create a pointer to the class as member and pass to the static function?

Comment: This makes no sense. What object do you expect to be potentially modifying in the body of a function *specifically* declared to be associated with no such instance? *Code* speaks volumes, and in this case would clarify what you're *really* trying to do.

Comment: @andrew You probably better should show us a small example code snippet of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a function to draw which is static and in that function, I am required to do a specfic check for which I already have a method defined in the same class. All I am trying to do is to call that method to perform that check and then do my drawing stuff accordingly.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894977/how-to-call-a-non-static-member-function-from-a-static-member-function-without-p) might be helpful.

Comment: @andrew So the method that does the check needs an instance of the class to be able to perform the check. The static method does not need an instance of the class to draw. Do you see how this is confusing? You need to present your problem more clearly to be able to get a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have the static function take a reference parameter of the class. Example:

```
struct Foo {
    void func() { }

    static void static_func(Foo& obj)
    {
        obj.func();
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
Foo foo;
Foo::static_func(foo);
```

You can instead use a `Foo* obj` parameter. In that case, you need to pass a pointer obviously (`Foo::static_func(&foo);`).

With that being said, your function looks like it shouldn't be static to begin with. Make it non-static.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming any instance of the class will do, why can't the static function just create its own temporary class instance ? Especially if there is a default constructor.
For example, the code below compiles correctly:

```
class Circle
{
public:
    Circle(double centerX, double centerY, double radius);
    Circle() : Circle(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)  // unit circle by default
    {}

    inline double  getRadius()  { return radius; };
    inline double  getArea()    { return area; };

    static  double computePi();   // HERE

private:
    double   centerX, centerY, radius, area;
};

Circle::Circle(double centerX, double centerY, double radius)
    : centerX(centerX), centerY(centerY), radius(radius)
{
    area = 3.14159*radius*radius;
}

double Circle::computePi()  // static class function, no "this" allowed
{
    Circle   tmpC1;  // temporary instance here !
    Circle*  tmpThis = &tmpC1;

    double  radius = tmpThis->getRadius();
    double  area   = tmpThis->getArea();
    double  pi     = area / (radius*radius);

    return pi;
}
```

OK, the semantics looks a bit hairy, but maybe it looks better in your own context.